# Android crash while using GSON Library and ProGuard

Tags: android, gson, proguard

I am using the following Proguard configuration with GSON library:

```
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard 
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature  

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Keep any class that intereracts with GSON
-keep class com.trifecta.engine.api.** { *; }
```

But while testing exported apk i am getting the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method 
"void com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$a.a(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter, java.lang.Object)"
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:546)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:525)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:480)
       at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:460)
```

I have researched for the problem here on SO and i followed the Proguard configuration from: [https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg] but still no success. [1](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this snippet and let me know

```
## GSON 2.2.4 specific rules ##

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
```

Comment: I think `-keepattributes EnclosingMethod` and `-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }` are new, although i am going to give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Wow. `-keepattributes EnclosingMethod` has some magic behind it, it is the only thing that was missing.

Comment: Hi! Can you please tell me how to deal with JNI while still using ProGuard?

Comment: Did't understand JNI?Dow you want a proguard configuration for that

Comment: Yes. Actually i am using PjSip in a project, which user Native C methods and some .so files. After enabling ProGuard, the Voice is missing in the Internet call.

Comment: CSIPSImple also uses PjSip for Voip Calling, and there Proguard configuration is: https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/CSipSimple/proguard.cfg

Comment: My wild guess is that `-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}` will do the trick.