# Proguard Overflow of unsigned short value

Tags: android, proguard

After adding a jar file containing some functionality that I need to my application, my proguard build hasn't been working. the error message I get after running my proguard build is:

```
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error while writing class [proguard/optimize/gson/_OptimizedTypeAdapterFactory] (Overflow of unsigned short value [93362])
Thread(Tasks limiter_1): destruction
```

Is there any way to exclude that jar file from being checked by ProGuard? I'm using ProGuard v6.2.2. I suspected the issue would be GSON since i had issues with it before this error.

I've also checked and researched answers here such as [Proguard [ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Overflow of unsigned short value ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200033/proguard-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-overflow-of-unsigned-short-value)

[Android crash while using GSON Library and ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263210/android-crash-while-using-gson-library-and-proguard)

[#732 Exception while handling very long string argument](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/732/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read more about ProGuard configuration and optimizations here:

https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage/optimizations

but in your case you can exclude the gson library that is throwing the exception like this:

```
-optimizations !library/gson
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a known bug. Until this had been rectified, you can only disable the code optimization:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/string
```

Or disable optimization altogether with `-dontoptimize`. Or just use R8 instead ...

That one linked answer which suggests a version-downgrade might also work.